# (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied with pygments.rb

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pygments

I have been really struggling with installing pygments.rb and did not find solution whatsoever.

This is the error code:

```
PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop> gem install pygments.rb

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink - (vendor/pygments-main/scripts/debug_lexer.py, C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/
```

2.3.0/gems/pygments.rb-1.1.1/vendor/pygments-main/scripts/find_error.py)

Comment: Please edit your error so that is easier to read

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb/issues/176).  The reporter indicates:

> For some reason, when the gem is packaged and subsequently installed,
>   the symlink from find_error.py to debug_lexer.py in
>   vendor/pygments-main/scripts. Perhaps we can either delete this
>   symlink or reify it during packaging.
>
> ...
>
> I guess RubyGems recently started supporting symlinks when packaging,
>   which is why this all of a sudden became a problem.